# Good way to create a immutable class with modifiers (thread-safe)

Tags: java, multithreading, immutability, final, volatile

I have a case when I want to avoid defensive copies, for data which might nevertheless be modified, but is usually simply read, and not written to. So, I'd like to use immutable objects, with functional mutator methods, which is kind of usual (java lombok is able to do it more or less automatically). The way I proceed is the following:

```
public class Person {
    private String name, surname;
    public Person(String name, String surname) {....}
    // getters...

    // and instead of setters
    public Person withName(String name) {
       Person p= copy(); // create a copy of this...
       p.name= name;
       return p;           
    }

   public Person copy() {....}         
}
```

So, to get a copy of the person with a different name, I would call

```
p= new Person("Bar", "Alfred");
...
p= p.withName("Foo");
```

In practice, the objects are rather large (and I ended up using serialization to avoid the burden of writing the copy code).

Now, while browsing the web, I see a potential concurrency problem with this implementation, as my fields are not final, and thus, concurrent access might see the returned copy, for instance, without the new name change (as there is no warrantee on the order of operation in this context).

Of course, I can't make my fields final, with the current implementation, as I first do a copy, and then change the data in the copy.

So, I'm looking for a good solution for this problem.

I might use volatile, but I feel it's not a good solution.

Another solution would be to use the builder pattern:

```
class PersonBuilder {
   String name, surname; ....
}

public class Person {
   private final String name, surname;

   public Person(PersonBuilder builder) {...}

   private PersonBuilder getBuilder() {
      return new PersonBuilder(name, surname);
   }

  public Person withName(String name) {
     PersonBuilder b= getBuilder();
     b.setName(name);
     return new Person(b);
  }
}
```

Is there any problem here, and above all, is there a more elegant way of doing the same thing ?

Comment: If your class is immutable, then it can't have modifiers, by definition. But a rather interesting problem...

Comment: What I do is have mutable data which is local to only one thread.  This avoids needing to copying large objects and may out perform using multiple threads with large immutable objects.

Comment: How do you want to manage your "instead of setters withXX functions`, one per attribute on only for certain attributes ?

Comment: for most attributes, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at Guava's [immutable collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained), such as [immutable list](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java) and how they create lists from builders etc.

The idiom is the following:

```
List<String> list1 = ImmutableList.of("a","b","c"); // factory method
List<String> list2 = ImmutableList.builder() // builder pattern
  .add("a")
  .add("b")
  .add("c")
  .build();

List<String> list3 = ...  // created by other means
List<String> immutableList3 = ImmutableList.copyOf(list3); // immutable copy, lazy if already immutable
```

I really like the idiom above. For an entity builder I would take the following approach:

```
Person johnWayne = Person.builder()
  .firstName("John")
  .lastName("Wayne")
  .dob("05-26-1907")
  .build();

Person johnWayneClone = johnWayne.copy() // returns a builder!
  .dob("06-25-2014")
  .build();
```

The builder here can be obtained from an existing instance via the `copy()` method or  via a static method on the `Person` class (a private constructor is recommended) that return a person builder.

Note that the above mimics a little Scala's [case classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107) in that you can create a copy from an existing instance.

Finally, don't forget to follow the [guidelines for immutable classes](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29):

- make the class final **or** make all getters final (if the class can be extended);
- make all fields final and private;
- initialize all fields in the constructor (which can be private if you provide a builder and/or factory methods);
- make defensive copies from getters if returning mutable objects (mutable collections, dates, third party classes, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I like the way your system avoids duplicating methods (no need to have a setXXX in the builder PLUS a withXXX method in the class... Plus it also avoids unnecessary duplications of the object data when more than one field is modified.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to separate your interfaces surrounding such objects into an immutable variant (providing getters) and a mutable variant (providing getters and setters).

```
public interface Person {
   String getName();
}

public interface MutablePerson extends Person {
   void setName(String name);
}
```

It doesn't solve the mutability of the object *per se* but it does offer some guarantees that when you pass around the object using the *immutable interface* reference, you know that the code you're passing this to won't change your object. Obviously you need to control the references to the underlying object and determine the subset of functionality that has control of a reference via the mutable interface.

It doesn't solve the underlying problem and I would favour immutable objects until I definitely need a mutable version. The builder approach works nicely, and you can integrate it within the object to give a modifier thus:

```
Person newPerson = existingPerson.withAge(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your fields final and your modifier methods directly create new objects?

```
public class Person {
    private final String name, surname;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {....}
    // getters...

    // and instead of setters
    public Person withName(String newName) {
       return new Person(newName, surname);         
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how viable this may be for larger/more complex objects such as OP's, though...

Comment: The OP indicated that the actual objects are much larger, and probably would have many modifier methods, which would quickly become very complex with your solution.

Comment: @GriffeyDog my solution is less complex than OP Builder version which still uses a Builder constructor with all the parameters `new PersonBuilder(name, surname);` so I don't see what the complaint is.  No matter how any of these solutions is written at some point all the fields have to be copied over.

Comment: The builder constructor would take the original Person object as argument. It's admittedly more verbose than your solution, but it avoids constructors with long lists of arguments, which can be difficult to read/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem boils down to this:  You want a method that *safely publishes* an effectively immutable, almost-but-not-quite-faithful copy of an effectively immutable object.

I'd go with the builder solution:  It's verbose as all get out, but Eclipse helps with that, and it allows all of the published objects to be *actually* immutable.  Actual immutability makes safe publication a no-brainer.

If I wrote it, it'd look like this:

```
class Person {
    public static final FooType DEFAULT_FOO = ...;
    public static final BarType DEFAULT_BAR = ...;
    public static final BazType DEFAULT_BAZ = ...;
    ...

    private final FooType foo;
    private final BarType bar;
    private final BazType baz;
    ...

    private Person(Builder builder) {
        this.foo = builder.foo;
        this.bar = builder.bar;
        this.baz = builder.baz;
        ...
    }

    public FooType getFoo() { return foo; }
    public BarType getBar() { return bar; }
    public BazType getBaz() { return baz; }
    ...

    public Person cloneWith(FooType foo) {
        return new Builder(this).setFoo(foo).build();
    }

    public Person cloneWith(BarType bar) {
        return new Builder(this).setBar(bar).build();
    }

    public Person cloneWith(FooType foo, BarType bar) {
        return new Builder(this).setFoo(foo).setBar(bar).build();
    }

    ...

    public class Builder{
        private FooType foo;
        private BarType bar;
        private BazType baz;
        ...

        public Builder() {
            foo = DEFAULT_FOO;
            bar = DEFAULT_BAR;
            baz = DEFAULT_BAZ;
            ...
        }

        public Builder(Person person) {
            foo = person.foo;
            bar = person.bar;
            baz = person.baz;
            ...
        }

        public Builder setFoo(FooType foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setBar(BarType bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setBaz(BazType baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
            return this;
        }

        ...

        public Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many fields you intend to change. You could make special *Changed* objects like:

```
interface Person {
     public String getForeName();
     public String getSurName();
 }

class RealPerson implements Person {
    private final String foreName;
    private final String surName;

    public RealPerson (String foreName, String surName) {
        this.foreName = foreName;
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getForeName() {
        return foreName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }

    public Person setSurName (String surName) {
        return new PersonWithSurnameChanged(this, surName);
    }

}

class PersonWithSurnameChanged implements Person {
    final Person original;
    final String surName;

    public PersonWithSurnameChanged (Person original, String surName) {
        this.original = original;
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getForeName() {
        return original.getForeName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }
}
```

This may also mitigate the problem you have with cloning heavy objects.

Comment: Quite elegant :-) (but, alas I might have too many fields). Of course, it also keeps all the successive states of the object in memory, but this can actually be a feature if I want to keep an history (which is indeed the case).

Comment: @khaemuaset - Don't forget the [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class if you want to automate the pass-through process.